# wordpress if statement error not inserting php code required

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I am "trying" to do some work on wordpress site but coming up against an issue with an if/else statement. Below is my code:

```
 <?php    if(is_page(9)):
 'get_new_royalslider(1)';   
  else:
  echo '<p>Other content</p>';   
  endif;      
   ?>
```

I am trying to insert the php code given for the Royalslide . Am I doing this part right ? I can get the else content to load in the other pages so that part is working.

Thanks

Comment: So the else part works, but not the if part?

Comment: Presumably `get_new_royalslider` is a function and shouldn't be in quotes - typically (by convention) the prefix *"get"* is also associated with functionality that returns values rather than prints so you may need to put an `echo` statement in front of it too...

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code to

```
<?php    if(is_page(9)):
  echo get_new_royalslider(1);   
  else:
  echo '<p>Other content</p>';   
  endif;      
?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php    if(is_page(9)):
  echo do_shortcode('[new_royalslider id="1"]');
  else:
  echo '<p>Other content</p>';   
  endif;      
?>
```

should fix your problem. Either way should work for you.

Comment: You have a syntax error in `echo get_new_royalslider(1';`

Comment: Thanks...er I was making sure people were awake ;)